# Struts result JSP 404

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, struts2, http-status-code-404

I'm new to Struts2, just finished a no action mapped issue, my action new will be execute, but while it return to JSP, there is always **404**. Tried to set namespace and result like following, but still don't get it work.

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>

  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WebContent/jsp/" />

  <package name="default" extends="json-default">
    <action name="testAction" class="tw.com.rrstudio.java.test.TestAction" method="execute">
      <result name="login">index.jsp</result>
      <result name="success">TestAction.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>

</struts>
```

Also tried remove convention result path and set result as this

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default">
  <action name="testAction" class="tw.com.rrstudio.java.test.TestAction" method="execute">
    <result name="login">/jsp/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/jsp/TestAction.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

But still gives 404.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>tw.com.rrstudio.java.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>HTTP://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```

my action java code

```
package tw.com.rrstudio.java.test;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
  public HttpServletRequest request;
  private String name="";

  public String execute() throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("Debug: name="+name);
    System.out.println("Debug: path="+request.getContextPath());
    System.out.println("Debug: path="+request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
    if(name!=null && !"".equals(name))
    {return "success";}
    else
    {return "login";}
  }

  @Override
  public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
  {this.request=request;}

  public String getName()
  {return name;}

  public void setName(String name)
  {this.name=name;}
}
```

While I call my action, it do printed debug message like this,

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Test/testAction.action

  Debug: name=

  Debug: path=/Struts2Test

  Debug: path=D:\eclipse\workspace2.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Struts2Test\
- http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Test/testAction.action?name=XYZ

  Debug: name=XYZ

  Debug: path=/Struts2Test

  Debug: path=D:\eclipse\workspace2.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Struts2Test\

but always give me a 404 page, and no any message.

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

type Status report
message 
description The requested resource is not available.
```

BTW, here's my package structure.

```
+Struts2Test
  +Struts2Test/src
    +tw.com.rrstudio.java.test
      -Struts2Test/src/tw/com/rrstudio/java/test/TestAction.java
  +Struts2Test/build
  +Struts2Test/WebContent
    +Struts2Test/WebContent/img
    +Struts2Test/WebContent/jsp
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/jsp/error.jsp
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/jsp/index.jsp
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/jsp/TestAction.jsp
    +Struts2Test/WebContent/META-INF
    +Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF
      +Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes
        -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties
        -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml
        +Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
        -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
        -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml
        -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts2-action.xml
        -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Please give any tips or suggestions, I appreciate for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the JSP is in the war once it is built ? Check if the structure deployed is the same of the one you have in your IDE

Comment: I checked again, both IDE(eclipse) deploy path and WAR file do have those jsp files exist in JSP folder.

Comment: Server log gives me this **127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2016:17:23:04 +0800] "GET /Struts2Test/testAction.action HTTP/1.1" 404 992** ......what I gonna to do ?

Comment: Is there any way I can know what URL the action really response and cause 404 ?

Comment: put the struts2-config-browser-plugin

Comment: Thanks but I already put it, any more suggestions ?

Comment: Well, and what do you see when you open the config-browser plugin's page, and click on your action ? Take a couple of screenshots and put them in your question, including at least the action mapping and the results mapping

Comment: Sorry I can't upload any image due to office's stupid network rule... Here's action default location *Default location:
/Struts2/index.do*, and results *success
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult
location = index.jsp*

Comment: In your code you've posted `testAction`, here you're saying `index.do`. You've specified the Convention Result Path in properties, then you're defining the action in XML (which means avoiding the Convention plugin). AND in that result, you're saying `/jsp/TestAction.jsp` instead of `/WebContent/jsp/TestAction.jsp`... the whole thing is a mess. Restart from scratches, possibly from a Struts2 archetype, then start adding things until it breaks. When it breaks, you know what it is.

Comment: @RRTW Your best bet troubleshooting this issue is on Spring, since you may be have problems with [Struts-Spring](http://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html) integration.